# How to use `\newline` after an item list?

Tags: lists, line-breaking, itemize

Concretely, this is what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item This
    \item That
    \item Where
\end{itemize}
%if I put \newline or \\ here it does not work. Why? 
I am doing it here to test this.
\end{document}
```

Where the item list ends, I want to give some linespacing but neither `\newline` nor `\\` is working. Why is that?

Comment: Are you trying to start a new paragraph?

Comment: I wonder also about that `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}` - line.

Comment: @ChristianH. not normal to use `\par` explicitly, a blank line is enough.

Comment: If you don't want to start a new paragraph, maybe `\\\` at the end of the last item (before `\end{itemize}`)?

Comment: @JosephWright, You can say that, yes.

Comment: @cfr, can you please elaborate? I will be grateful.

Comment: @ChristianH. Removed `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}`. Its part of code. Plus `\par` did not work for some reason.

Comment: @user1343318 Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Basically the problem is that `\\` ends a line, but after an `itemize` there exist no line that can be ended.

Mi very simple solution to case like these is to put a "fake line" by adding a space and then the newline.
This will be like:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item one
  \item two
\end{itemize}
\  \\
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Clever solution!

Answer (score 23):

The right way to add a "blank line" would be to insert some horizontal space.

Inserting `\bigskip` you have the corresponding space:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item This
    \item That
    \item Where
\end{itemize}
\bigskip
I am doing it here to test this.
```

If you also want to start a new (indented) paragraph add a blank line:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item This
    \item That
    \item Where
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

I am doing it here to test this.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item This
    \item That
    \item Where
\end{itemize}
\bigskip
I am doing it here to test this.

\begin{itemize}
    \item This
    \item That
    \item Where
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

I am doing it here to test this.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here are some examples with explanations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item This
    \item That
    \item Where
\end{itemize}
I am doing it here to test this.

\begin{itemize}
    \item This
    \item That
    \item Where
\end{itemize}
Putting \verb|\newline| or \verb|\\| here will cause an error that there is `no line here to break`. This is because a new line has already been started by the ending of the list. Putting the same command here\\
will work because this is in the middle of a line.

\begin{itemize}
    \item This
    \item That
    \item Where
\end{itemize}

One way to get extra horizontal space is to start a new paragraph.

\begin{itemize}
    \item But you
    \item may \emph{just}
    \item want space\\
\end{itemize}
without a paragraph break.

\begin{itemize}
    \item If you
    \item want
    \item a little\\[-.5em]
\end{itemize}
less space
\begin{itemize}
    \item or you
    \item want
    \item a lot\\[5em]
\end{itemize}
more.

\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image: Variations on a spatial theme]

Comment: This produces underfull hboxes...

Comment: @karlkoeller Is that bad? I mean they are warnings but you know in this case why you get the warnings and that you in fact want the space. In general, I interpret warnings as 'You may want to check... because normally you wouldn't want...' rather than necessarily demonstrating that there is a problem. (It is only a problem if you didn't want... - normally, but not always, the case.)